# EXCEL: How can I use a custom function created in VB as formula for conditional formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, visual-basic

I created a VB script to validate a personal document from my country (just like the Social Security number in USA).

It is BOOLEAN, receives the number as param and returns only TRUE or FALSE if it's valid. Now I need to use this function as formula for conditional formatting. There's any way to do this?

Comment: Yes you can. What have you tried and where are you running into issues?

Comment: You can read my script [here](https://goo.gl/v78Na8).

Comment: ... and a screenshot of the error [here](http://i.minus.com/iEsGIfUpIhnzL.png). The literally translation for the error message is: "It cannot use this kind of references for a formula Conditional Formatting."